# Change new html page on swipe of class -idangerous swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have two tab:

```
<div class="swiper-container container_height">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div>
                                <div class="invest_nav1">
                                    <figure>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img src="../images/accountlist.png" width="25" height="23">
                                      <figcaption id="VisitScheduleListHeaderLabelVisitScheduleList"></figcaption></a>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <div class="invest_nav2" id="dvVisitedScheduleActivityLstTab" style="display:none;">
                                    <figure>
                                        <a href="VisitedScheduleActivityList.html">
                                            <img src="../images/accountlist.png" width="25" height="23">
                                      <figcaption id="VisitScheduleListHeaderLabelVisitScheduleActivityList"></figcaption></a>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My expectation is if i swipe right page location.herf should change:
my code is:

```
<script>
        var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: '.pagination',

            paginationClickable: true
        })    
    </script>
```

Comment: do you have any error in console .

Comment: Can you provide a link to jsfiddle or smthing?